# Nomethoderror on watir webdriver ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

i am new to Watir. When I run this file in terminal, ruby TestJoinChange.rb, I get NoMethodError

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new

class TestJoinChange < Test::TestCase
  def test_join(logintype,usr,pwd)
    # open browser to page
    @browser.goto 'http://change.com'
  end
end
```

How do I pass parameter values? Why my function is returning no method error?

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the entire error message? What are you trying to do?

Comment: /Users/username/test/testfldr/TestJoinChange.rb:37: undefined method `test_join' for TestJoinChange:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: What happens if you replace `def test_join(logintype,usr,pwd)` with `def test_join`?

Comment: Then how do i pass parameter? I did try without parameters still didn't work.

Comment: Hi Zeljko, can u please help me with other question (posted @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503085/watir-webdriver-window-not-found) ...thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want parameters passed?

Answer (score 0):

"You have defined subroutine now you can pass values when you call that subroutine by making an object of the class."

your code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new

class TestJoinChange < Test::TestCase
  def test_join(logintype,usr,pwd)
    # open browser to page
    @browser.goto 'http://change.com'
  end
end
```

now just create an object for your class:

```
    obj = TestJoinChange.new    
# it will create object for your class and now call the subroutine and pass any value in that#
    obj.test_join("logintype_value", "user", "password")
```

Now you can use the values in your class by storing all passed values in to variables.