# watir webdriver - window not found

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Another watir issue. This code works until `add_task`...

After login, the auth window closes and goes back to main window with login key. But I get this error:

> hi there
>
> testing add_task
>
> [remote server] file:///var/folders/3w/b7rcpqfj7kl3wtv56jt99yx00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20120919-9069-1ua1lm9/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10212:in `unknown': Window not found. The browser window may have been closed. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Login   
def basic_auth(logintype,usr,pwd)
    $browser.goto("http://change.com")
    $browser.link(:class,'joinchange').wait_until_present
    join_link = $browser.link(:class,'joinchange')
    join_link.click

    $browser.window(:title, 'Sign In').wait_until_present
    $browser.window(:title, 'Sign In').use
    if logintype == 'fb'
        $browser.link(:name, 'login-facebook id=').click
        $browser.text_field(:id,'email').set(usr)
        $browser.text_field(:id,'pass').set(pwd)
        puts 'form submit'
        sleep 3
        $browser.form(:id,'login_form').submit
        puts 'hello world'
    else
        $browser.text_field(:id,'lgnId').set('changes')
        $browser.text_field(:id,'pwdId').set('letmeinnow')
        sleep 3
        $browser.form(:name,'LoginActionForm').submit
        puts 'hi there'
    end
end
def add_task
    puts "testing add_task"
    $browser.link(:class,'nextStep').click  
end

end

$browser = Watir::Browser.new
login = Login.new
login.basic_auth('test','usr','pwd')
sleep 3
login.add_task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that after switching to the Sign In popup window, the script does not switch out of it. So during add_task when it tries to click the link, it is trying in the Sign In popup, which is closed.

In the `basic_auth` method, you want to pass the actions you want performed in the popup as a block to the `window.use` method.

So you want:

```
$browser.window(:title, 'Sign In').use do 
    if logintype == 'fb'
        $browser.link(:name, 'login-facebook id=').click
        $browser.text_field(:id,'email').set(usr)
        $browser.text_field(:id,'pass').set(pwd)
        puts 'form submit'
        sleep 3
        $browser.form(:id,'login_form').submit
        puts 'hello world'
    else
        $browser.text_field(:id,'lgnId').set('changes')
        $browser.text_field(:id,'pwdId').set('letmeinnow')
        sleep 3
        $browser.form(:name,'LoginActionForm').submit
        puts 'hi there'
    end
end
```

(Notice the `do` added at the end of the first line and the extra `end` at the end.)

Comment: Sorry, accidentally lost the `end` for the if statement. Code updated.